# Index error in keras after reshaping array

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am using a .csv file for the image data, which I reshape into a 2d numpy array to represent images.

I am not sure what I am missing, and I keep getting an "IndexError: list index out of range" when fitting the model.

```
train_data = pd.read_csv('sign_mnist_train.csv')
test_data = pd.read_csv('sign_mnist_test.csv')

train_labels = train_data.pop('label').to_numpy().reshape(-1, 1)
test_labels = test_data.pop('label').to_numpy().reshape(-1, 1)

train_images = train_data.to_numpy().reshape(-1, 28, 28, 1) / 255.0
test_images = test_data.to_numpy().reshape(-1, 28, 28, 1) / 255.0

def make_model():
    model = models.Sequential()
    
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=(28, 28, 1)))
    model.add(layers.MaxPool2D((2,2)))
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.MaxPool2D(2,2))
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu'))

    model.add(layers.Flatten())
    model.add(layers.Dense(64))
    model.add(layers.Dense(25))

    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy,
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
    
    return model

model = make_model()
model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=5, validation_data(test_images, test_labels))
```

The full traceback:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVF6v.png)      [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqYNH.png)      [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9QGf.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post the code which is producing error and the full traceback.

Comment: @Frightera, I updated my comment with that. I hope that is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose the issue is from this `train.data`, as per the test images you named them `test_data`.
Also you're reshaping them into a 4D Tensor and not a 2D Tensor based on the code.

```
train_images = train_data.to_numpy().reshape(-1, 28, 28, 1) 
test_images = test_data.to_numpy().reshape(-1, 28, 28, 1) 

train_images = train_images / 255.0
test_images = test_images / 255.0
```

Edit:
Check if applying one-hot encoding to the target variables helps

```
train_labels = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(train_labels)
```

Comment: But if I input the 3 dimensions (width, height, colour channels) from the 4D tensor into a Conv2D layer, wouldn't it automatically find the 4th dimension? I am not sure why that would be a problem.

Comment: Train images after reshaping it will have 4D which are `(batch_size, width, height, color_channel)`. It's not an issue I am just pointing out that its not a 2D Tensor that's being created.

Comment: @user if this answers your question please do accept and upvote it.

Comment: I am still not sure what's wrong, and the error remains.

Comment: @user check if you one-hot encoding the target variables in the edited answer and also include the whole model architecture in the question.

Comment: There was something wrong with the loss function I used. It's all good now, thanks.